# Association between category,subcategory and gig

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, mvvm

My website has Category->Subcategory->Gigs *`(by gigs i mean lots of adds)`*

Below are the relationships between the 3 models.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories
end


class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :gigs
end


class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subcategory
end
```

**Question:**

> What rails migrations should i use to make the required relationship
>   between them in schema.rb,for example ("should i create category_id,or
>   subcategory_id,or gig_id...),if yes in what table should they go,i got
>   quite confused about it.

*Thank you for your time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "belongs_to" relationship always requires a foreign key on that table.

With that being said, your *gigs* table should have

```
t.integer :user_id
t.integer :subcategory_id
```

and your *subcategories* table should have

```
t.integer :category_id
```

hope that helps!

Comment: After i created all the Categories,and subcategories names,for example Car Main category,how do i link it to window,tax,road,tyre subcategories?

Comment: assuming that you have `car_main = Category.create(:name => "Car Main")` when you set up a subcategory, you can build it with the category set to the car_main variable: `window = Subcategory.create(:name => "window", :category => car_main)`